# Прямая работа с аргументами функции

Tags: php, функции, global-variables

Как я могу работать с переменными напрямую в функции.

Вот у меня есть функция: `myfunction($var)`.
Можно ли сделать так, чтобы функция `myfunction` не возвращала определенное значение, а изменяла значение самой переменной $var?

Comment: [Передача аргументов по ссылке](http://www.php.net/manual/ru/functions.arguments.php#functions.arguments.by-reference)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Конечно можно, передайте параметр по ссылке, и будет счастье!

Код:

```
<?php
 
function my(&$var){
    $var++;
}
 
$a = 0;
my($a);
echo $a;
```

Comment: Я, конечно, знал, что такая чтука работает с элементами массива в foreach, но чтобы в самой функции! Спасибо большое Вам)

Answer (score 2):

**static** //сохраняет значение переменной в функции после ее изменения

```
$a = 1;
function staticTest($var){
     static $name;
     $name += $var;
}
staticTest($a); //1
staticTest($a); //2
staticTest($a); //3
```

...или воспользоваться **global** переменной

Comment: @HA3IK, Ваш ответ не в тему, но плюсик Вам от меня. Теперь я знаю новый способ быдлокодить на РНР.

Comment: http://hashcode.ru/users/481/reinraus Дауж... спасибо ) Но вопрос я действительно не так понял )

Answer (score 0):

Не уверен что правильно вас понял, но всеже не это ли вам надо?

```
$var = 1;
function myFunc () {
global $var;
$var++;
}
myFunc();
echo $var;
```

Comment: Использование глобальных переменных, безусловно, работает, однако крайне не рекомендуется. Отследить изменение (а значит, и потенциальный баг) требует значительных усилий (как минимум, брейкпоинтов по всему приложению). Вместо глобальных переменных лучше использовать шаблон реестра (свободное отслеживание и запрет изменений), который позволит делать то же самое, однако практически гарантированно все сведется к передаче данных по ссылке (если от реестра требуется максимально удобно обновлять записи), и в результате окажется, что кроме ответа ua6xh верных нет.